# JavaFX: ContextMenu after a row has been filled with an entry?

Tags: java, javafx

I am using [this link](https://gist.github.com/james-d/7758918) for creating a ContextMenu for each table row. Right now I'm running into problems because I'm not sure how to attach a ContextMenu after the 'type' has been inserted into a row.

Lets say I'm using a .zip editor program, and it lists the contents. I have an Image, and a text file, and some other stuff, all of them are under a class called *Entry*. My table's generic type is 'Entry', and I'd like to be able to create a context menu for each entry based on it's underlying subclass type (like an ImageEntry might return a menu item to open it up in an image editor...etc).

Right now I have a generic context menu for everything, but it's not great displaying a menu item about opening a text file with an image editor...

Is this possible to do? If so, what is the proper way to go about doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a listener to the row's `itemProperty` (which represents the item displayed in the row) and update the context menu when it changes:

```
    table.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<Person>, TableRow<Person>>() {  
        @Override  
        public TableRow<Person> call(TableView<Person> tableView) {  
            final TableRow<Person> row = new TableRow<>();  
            final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();  

            row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldPerson, newPerson) -> {
                contextMenu.getItems().clear();
                // add items to context menu depending on value of newPerson
                // ...
            });

           // Set context menu on row, but use a binding to make it only show for non-empty rows:  
            row.contextMenuProperty().bind(  
                    Bindings.when(row.emptyProperty())  
                    .then((ContextMenu)null)  
                    .otherwise(contextMenu)  
            );  
            return row ;  
        }  
    });
```